# 30 runs in an over

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A cricket partnership can score zero to six runs per ball with equal probability. What is the chance of 30 runs being scored in an over of six balls, assuming no outs or extras?

Comment: For non-cricket lovers, there are usually $6$ balls in an over

Comment: maybe it's easier to work out how many distinct ways he can drop the 6 runs, if each score drops 0-6 runs (order could be important)

Comment: What does "throwing a ball" mean here? Might it be "bowling a no-ball"?

Comment: is this a 'real world' simulation?  the prob of any score 0-6 is 1/7 - is that right?  That isn't realistic though, because a 5 is rarer than most other scores.   I don't know what 'throw' means either - only a fielder throws the ball - are you simulating detailed play?

Comment: Also note that a batsman scoring an odd number of runs will usually not face the next ball in the over

Comment: Also note that many of the users on this site don't know the rules of cricket...

Comment: Do over-throw runs count? If it does, the number of possibilities would increase significantly.

Comment: You could rephrase this without any reference to cricket e.g. what is the  probability of a total of 30 from 6 7-sided dice.  7-sided dice are unusual but the idea would be understood by more people that cricket.  Better still, look at dice problems starting with the probabilities of various totals from 2 dice, 3 dice, etc.  If you learn how they work then come back to this problem.  Despite quite liking cricket, the notion that scores of 0 to 6 are equally likely is unappealing.

Comment: Hey @badjohn,I don't know why you are saying that they are not equally likely if all conditions are taken ideal with no mistake ,if you take real scenario then the factors that the runs depend on; 1) Batsman's mood on that day.2)His practice .3) Batsman's eye tracking mechanism.4) His physical strength. ,5) His mate runner's capability.6) Bowler's ability to throw balls correctly 7)bla bla.. bla...,just ignore this

Comment: @satyatech Yes, those are all factors but ...  I assume that you have watched quite a lot of cricket.  How often have you seen a batsman not run (get zero)?  Too many times to count, I expect.  1 run?  Not so many but still a lot.  As someone else said, 5 is rather unlikely, I don't think that I have ever seen that.  So, you could calculate the probability assuming that all of 0 to 7 were equally likely but it would have little to do with the real world.  That's not a criticism, this is a maths group and unworldly stuff is common.  I just wanted you to understand that.

Comment: @satyatech 0 to 7 was a mistake, 0 to 6 of course.  There may be sites with cricket statistics.  If you get statistics of the frequency of 0 runs, 1 run, etc then you could get a better answer for the probability of various scores for an over.  If you want to proceed on the equally likely basis then study dice problems, they will be very similar.

Comment: This is such a silly set-up (scoring 5 is as likely as scoring 1?) that its silliness distracts us from the underlying mathematics. Why don't you just throw dice instead, satyatech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider that it is equally likely for any of the (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) to occur on each ball. Than the ways in which 30 run can be scored could be calculated by the permutation of **(6,6,6,6,6,0), (6,6,6,6,5,1), (6,6,6,6,4,2), (6,6,6,6,3,3)** add all the ways than divide by total no of ways the over can happen which is 7^6. 
Total no. of ways to score 30 would be `6!/5!+6!/4!+6!/4!+6!/(4!*2!)`. which equals 81, so your desired probability is equals 81/7^6. 
*I am new to stack exchange and don't know how to write mathematical symbols properly so feel free to edit my answer.*